# ssh login fails: debug1: update_known_hosts: known hosts file ~/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist

Tags: linux, ssh

For some time now I can no longer log in to my raspberry pi server via ssh:

```
ssh -v pi@192.168.0.47
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.47 [192.168.0.47] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2+rpt1
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2+rpt1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.47:22 as 'pi'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:OjhTMb87orYM2OyCipPLrt2Yx+ROc46ezsVr3nBTG7u
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/known_hosts does not exist
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts does not exist
debug1: hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 does not exist
The authenticity of host '192.168.0.47 (192.168.0.47)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:OjhTMb87orYM2OyCipPLrt2Yx+ROc46ezsVr3nBTG7u.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
debug1: SELinux support disabled
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.0.47' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pi@192.168.0.47's password: 
Authenticated to 192.168.0.47 ([192.168.0.47]:22) using "password".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/known_hosts for 192.168.0.47 / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/known_hosts2 for 192.168.0.47 / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_ADDRESS = "de_DE.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_NAME = "de_DE.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_MONETARY = "de_DE.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_PAPER = "de_DE.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "de_DE.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_IDENTIFICATION = "de_DE.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_TELEPHONE = "de_DE.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_MEASUREMENT = "de_DE.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_TIME = "de_DE.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_NUMERIC = "de_DE.UTF-8"
debug1: client_global_hostkeys_private_confirm: server used untrusted RSA signature algorithm ssh-rsa for key 0, disregarding
Learned new hostkey: ECDSA SHA256:hC6CZEjEKpsjtnXzPGLSfnGyRnpuOZPLfFsOqjuiDYi
Adding new key for 192.168.0.47 to /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/known_hosts: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:hC6CZEjEKpsjtnXzPGLSfnGyRnpuOZPLfFsOqjuiDYi
debug1: update_known_hosts: known hosts file /home/masterofpuppets/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
```

I have no idea what this could be and I could not find anything helpful on the internet about the error message. I am using Xubuntu Linux and I have no idea what further details to add to be able to submit this question.

Edit: The problem must be with the Raspi, when I try to log in from another PC, the same error message comes up.